# SQL substring issue with multiple rows in one cell

Tags: c#, sql-server, substring

I have a SQL cell with multiple lines in 1 cell.
I want to select a specific row 2. I can use the substring option but I don't know how to set the second statement.
I have now:

```
substring( tbart.artdiscirption, charindex('\n', tbart.artdiscirption ) - 1 ,len(tbart.artdiscirption)) as short_article
```

in this substring I lose the first row but not the other rows (of course because I use the charindex and length of the string).

I tried a substring in substring but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: "I have a SQL cell with multiple lines in 1 cell." -- And that's a design flaw. If something isn't considered atomic, it doesn't belong in one column. It needs to be split in its atoms and these have to be stored in several columns or rows each.

Answer (score 0):

If 2016+, you can use a bit of JSON.

Note: Using the delimiter of `\n` works but is suspect you may really have `\r\n` which will work as well.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeCol nvarchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'Line 1
Line 2
Line 3'),
(2,'Line A
Line B
Line C'
)

Select A.ID
      ,Pos2 = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[1]')
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ( '["'+replace(string_escape(SomeCol,'json'),'\n','","')+'"]' ) ) B(S)
```

**Results**

```
ID  Pos2
1   Line 2
2   Line B
```